Why doesn't my binary find libwx_gtk3u_html-3.2.so.0?
I'm trying to build FileZilla on Linux and have my binary run without needing the hack of having LD_LIBRARY_PATH set in the terminal.  I've got the current directory structure:
FileZilla3
├── bin
│   ├── filezilla
│   ├── fzputtygen
│   ├── fzsftp
│   └── fzstorj
└── lib
    ├── libfilezilla.so.45
    ├── libfzclient-commonui-private-3.67.1.so
    ├── libfzclient-private-3.67.1.so
    ├── libgmp.so.10
    ├── libgnutls.so.30
    ├── libhogweed.so.6
    ├── libnettle.so.8
    ├── libsqlite3.so.0
    ├── libwx_baseu-3.2.so.0
    ├── libwx_baseu_xml-3.2.so.0
    ├── libwx_gtk3u_aui-3.2.so.0
    ├── libwx_gtk3u_core-3.2.so.0
    ├── libwx_gtk3u_html-3.2.so.0
    └── libwx_gtk3u_xrc-3.2.so.0

I've been putting the appropriate libraries into lib one by one, based on what's listed here:
$ eu-readelf -d filezilla

Dynamic segment contains 47 entries:
 Addr: 0x00000000004ed2d0  Offset: 0x4ec2d0  Link to section: [36] '.dynstr'
  Type              Value
  NEEDED            Shared library: [libfzclient-commonui-private-3.67.1.so]
  NEEDED            Shared library: [libfzclient-private-3.67.1.so]
  NEEDED            Shared library: [libfilezilla.so.45]
  NEEDED            Shared library: [libpugixml.so.1]
  NEEDED            Shared library: [libdbus-1.so.3]
  NEEDED            Shared library: [libwx_gtk3u_aui-3.2.so.0]
  NEEDED            Shared library: [libwx_gtk3u_xrc-3.2.so.0]
  NEEDED            Shared library: [libwx_gtk3u_core-3.2.so.0]
  NEEDED            Shared library: [libwx_baseu-3.2.so.0]
  NEEDED            Shared library: [libsqlite3.so.0]
  NEEDED            Shared library: [libgtk-3.so.0]
  NEEDED            Shared library: [libgdk-3.so.0]
  NEEDED            Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
  NEEDED            Shared library: [libm.so.6]
  NEEDED            Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
  NEEDED            Shared library: [libc.so.6]
  RUNPATH           Library runpath: [$ORIGIN/../lib]


However, when I now try to run the binary I get the following:
$ ./bin/filezilla
./bin/filezilla: error while loading shared libraries: libwx_gtk3u_html-3.2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Why can't it find libwx_gtk3u_html-3.2.so.0?  It's in the lib directory.  And why does it even require that file when it's not apparently required in the ELF?  Can it be pulled in by another SO file?

Turns out my libraries weren't looking for their required libraries in the same directory because they had no RUNPATH set.  I had to set it to look in the origin directory like so, and then they loaded properly:
patchelf --set-rpath "\$ORIGIN" ./libwx_gtk3u_xrc-3.2.so.0


You don't need to patch the elf, rather you can simply use LD_LIBRARY_PATH to specify where the libs are located.

Yeah but as my original question said, I don't want to have to set that env var.
